# File Permissions Error When Connecting to Excel via OLDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

This following code works correctly the first time I access the file to do a line count. However, when I attempt to open the same file to read the data, I get an error thrown on ExcelConnection.Open() which states that I do not have permission to access the file or it is already being used. Any thought as to why the file isn't being released after the first connection to it?

```
public static DataSet GetExcelWorkSheet(string pathName, string fileName)
        {
            string fileExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();

            OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(fileExtention == ".xls" ?
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + @"\" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=true;\"" :
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + @"\" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;ReadOnly=true;\"");
            OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            ExcelCommand.Connection = ExcelConnection;
            OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
            ExcelConnection.Open();

            // DataTable ExcelSheets = ExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            DataTable ExcelSheets = ExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            string CheckSheetName = ExcelSheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            string SpreadSheetName;
            int useMe = -1;

            if (CheckSheetName.ToUpper() != "SHEET1$")                 // Ok, they have renamed things
            {
                if (CheckSheetName.Substring(0, 5).ToUpper() == "SHEET")
                // if it does START with sheet then look for anything that
                // DOES NOT start with sheet
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < ExcelSheets.Rows.Count; x++)
                    {
                        if (ExcelSheets.Rows[x]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Substring(0, 5).ToUpper() != "SHEET")   // If is does not equal sheet then use it
                        {
                            useMe = x;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            SpreadSheetName = string.Format("[{0}]", useMe == -1 ? CheckSheetName : ExcelSheets.Rows[useMe]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

            try
            {
                DataSet ExcelDataSet = new DataSet();
                ExcelCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + SpreadSheetName;
                ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet);
                return ExcelDataSet;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ExcelConnection.Close();
                return new DataSet();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up.
                if (ExcelConnection != null)
                {
                    ExcelConnection.Close();
                    ExcelConnection.Dispose();
                }
                if (ExcelSheets != null)
                {
                    ExcelSheets.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close the connetion after the file has been read or the operation you have odne is completed....

ExcelConnection.Close();

Comment: I have done that in the finally block. When I step through the initial process, it runs through the finally correctly and closes the connection and dataobject which has a connection in it as well.